# Accessing the elements in a table is slower than calculating each time?

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, list-manipulation, summation, combinatorics

This is a follow-up of [How to accelerate combinations and sum calculations here?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114985/how-to-accelerate-combinations-and-sum-calculations-here)

I have tried all tricks but when N reaches 35 the time is still intimidating in a 16-core server, which is far better than my Mac 2.7 GHz Intel Core i5.

I was thinking that perhaps I could store all the binomials in a table like:

```
N = 80;
BinomialTable = ParallelTable[Binomial[i, j], {i, 1, N}, {j, 1, N}];
```

Then I changed all the `Binomial[x,y]` into `BinomialTable[[x]][[y]]` in the hope that instead of calculating the combinations each time, getting them from the table would be a better idea.

The new H is named HTable with all `Binomial[x,y]` replaced by `BinomialTable[[x]][[y]]`.

However, what I got is:

```
NmaxCompare = 6; 
A1 = 
 ParallelTable[
   H[i, j, k, l], {i, 1, NmaxCompare}, { j, 1, 
    NmaxCompare}, {k, 1, NmaxCompare}, {l, 1, NmaxCompare}] // 
  AbsoluteTiming;

AA1 = Table[
    H[i, j, k, l], {i, 1, NmaxCompare}, { j, 1, 
     NmaxCompare}, {k, 1, NmaxCompare}, {l, 1, NmaxCompare}] // 
   AbsoluteTiming;

B1 = ParallelTable[
    HTable[i, j, k, l], {i, 1, NmaxCompare}, { j, 1, 
     NmaxCompare}, {k, 1, NmaxCompare}, {l, 1, NmaxCompare}] // 
   AbsoluteTiming;

BB1 = Table[
    HTable[i, j, k, l], {i, 1, NmaxCompare}, { j, 1, 
     NmaxCompare}, {k, 1, NmaxCompare}, {l, 1, NmaxCompare}] // 
   AbsoluteTiming;
```

[image]

It seems there is too much overhead for getting the elements from the table?

Also, ParallelTable of getting elements directly (B1) cannot even beat Table of calculating the combinations each time(AA1).

Does anyone has any idea to save the time on combinations by avoiding calculating them each time? Thanks!

All the code needed here:

```
N = 80;
BinomialTable = ParallelTable[Binomial[i, j], {i, 1, N}, {j, 1, N}];

H[n1_, n2_, n3_, n4_] := 
(1/(4*Sqrt[n1*(n1 + 1)*n2*(n2 + 1)*n3*(n3 + 1)*n4*(n4 + 1)]))*
   Sum[(-1)^(m1 + m2 + m3 + m4)*Binomial[n1 + 1, m1 + 2]*Binomial[n2 + 1, m2 + 2]*Binomial[n3 + 1, m3 + 2]*Binomial[n4 + 1, m4 + 2]*
     Binomial[m1 + m3, m1]*Binomial[m2 + m4, m2]*(m1 + m3 + 1)*(m2 + m4 + 1)*
     (((m1 + m3 + 2)/2^(m1 + m3))*Sum[Binomial[m1 + m3 + k + 2, k]/2^k, {k, 0, m2 + m4 + 1}] + 
      ((m2 + m4 + 2)/2^(m2 + m4))*Sum[Binomial[m2 + m4 + l + 2, l]/2^l, {l, 0, m1 + m3 + 1}]), {m1, 0, n1 - 1}, {m2, 0, n2 - 1}, {m3, 0, n3 - 1}, 
    {m4, 0, n4 - 1}]

HTable[n1_, n2_, n3_, n4_] := 
(1/(4*Sqrt[n1*(n1 + 1)*n2*(n2 + 1)*n3*(n3 + 1)*n4*(n4 + 1)]))*
   Sum[(-1)^(m1 + m2 + m3 + m4)*BinomialTable[n1 + 1, m1 + 2]*BinomialTable[n2 + 1, m2 + 2]*BinomialTable[n3 + 1, m3 + 2]*BinomialTable[n4 + 1, m4 + 2]*
     BinomialTable[m1 + m3, m1]*BinomialTable[m2 + m4, m2]*(m1 + m3 + 1)*(m2 + m4 + 1)*
     (((m1 + m3 + 2)/2^(m1 + m3))*Sum[BinomialTable[m1 + m3 + k + 2, k]/2^k, {k, 0, m2 + m4 + 1}] + 
      ((m2 + m4 + 2)/2^(m2 + m4))*Sum[BinomialTable[m2 + m4 + l + 2, l]/2^l, {l, 0, m1 + m3 + 1}]), {m1, 0, n1 - 1}, {m2, 0, n2 - 1}, {m3, 0, n3 - 1}, 
    {m4, 0, n4 - 1}]
```

Comment: You expect readers to bounce to other questions to get code for a working example? No, just.... no. Please provide a *complete* minimal working example with *all* needed code.

Comment: "perhaps I could store all the binomials in a table" - *Mathematica* already caches internally.

Comment: @ciao done edited

Comment: @J.M. but it seems from input[359] and [360] getting from the table is quicker?

Comment: AIn't much of a difference, AFAICT. Try using `RepeatedTiming[]` as a check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a *very* quick-and-dirty, but gives 4X speed-up (7X with tweak for symmetry) on my crappy netbook for the n=8 case, don't have time or patience to test bigger cases to see scaling differences.

Perhaps a description of *what* you're trying to calculate? It appears to be some combinatorial problem, there may well be a much more efficient scheme to do what you want.

In any case, give this a whirl (and if you're going to iterate cases through various *n*, don't clear the helper functions between runs):

```
Clear[s1, s2, bc, mx, sq]
Hx[i_, j_, k_, l_] /; (i > j || k > l) = Missing[];
Hx[n1_, n2_, n3_, n4_] := Hx[n3, n4, n1, n2] =
  mx[n1, n2, n3, n4]*
   Sum[(-1)^(m1 + m2 + m3 + m4)*bc[n1 + 1, m1 + 2]*bc[n2 + 1, m2 + 2]*
     bc[n3 + 1, m3 + 2]*bc[n4 + 1, m4 + 2]*bc[m1 + m3, m1]*
     bc[m2 + m4, m2]*(m1 + m3 + 1)*(m2 + m4 + 1)*
     (sq[m1, m3]*s1[m1, m2, m3, m4] + (sq[m2, m4])*
        s2[m1, m2, m3, m4]), 
      {m1, 0, n1 - 1}, {m2, 0, n2 - 1}, {m3, 0,n3 - 1}, {m4, 0, n4 - 1}];

s1[m1_, m2_, m3_, m4_] := s1[m1, m2, m3, m4] = 
   Sum[bc[m1 + m3 + k + 2, k]/2^k, {k, 0, m2 + m4 + 1}];

s2[m1_, m2_, m3_, m4_] := s2[m1, m2, m3, m4] = 
   Sum[bc[m2 + m4 + l + 2, l]/2^l, {l, 0, m1 + m3 + 1}];

bc[a_, b_] := bc[a, b] = Binomial[a, b];

sq[a_, b_] := sq[a, b] = ((a + b + 2)/2^(a + b));

SetAttributes[mx, Orderless];
mx[n1_, n2_, n3_, n4_] := mx[n1, n2, n3, n4] = 
     (1/(4*Sqrt[n1*(n1 + 1)*n2*(n2 + 1)*n3*(n3 + 1)*n4*(n4 + 1)]));

(* to make a table, e.g.: *)
nn = 8
res2 = Table[Hx[a, b, c, d], {a, nn}, {b, nn}, {c, nn}, {d, nn}];
```

Comment: Cool! I also find this [Define a function recursively](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html). I was wondering could we do the same tweak for symmetry like `s2[m1_, m2_, m3_, m4_] := s2[m3, m2, m1, m4] ` like Hx?